# Is there any way to extract only single character words from a String?

Tags: java, string, char, extract

Given a string, eg "Hello a World b", is there any way I can just print out the characters 'a' and 'b' and ignore "Hello" and "World"?

I just want to print out the the single letter words and ignore the multi-letter strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the right regex...

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z]\\b").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Same result, but less code, is to remove all multi letter words then split on spaces:

```
for (String letter : str.replaceAll("\\w\\w+", "").trim().split(" +"))
    System.out.println(letter);
```

Comment: Tested it and got it to work exactly how I wanted it. Thank you so much! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

You need a mapping of emoticons and what character should replace it. Then iterate through the map, replace the emote (key) with the character (value) and your set.

Looks a bit like this

```
Map<String, String> emoticons = new HashMap<String, String>();
//fill it with emoticons and what string should replace it

String s = "Hello :) World :P";

for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: emoticons.entrySet()){
    s = s.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to use [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method from String class

```
List <String> emoticons = new ArrayList();

for(String emoticon : emoticons) {
       String input = "Hello :) World :P";
       boolean output= input.contains(emoticon);
       System.out.println("this emoticon "+emoticon+ is pressent);
}
```

I hope it helps :)